# How to send an email notification using python whenever there is a table is created in snowflake with the name %tbl%

Tags: python, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Whenever a table with the name %tbl% is created in Snowflake, I have to send an email to a particular recipient using Python. For this, I referred to the Snowflake Connector for Python topic in the documentation. I am finding it difficult to build code for this use case since I am a complete beginner.

Kindly help me with Python Sample code and links to refer if any. TIA

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach would be built-in [Setting Up Alerts Based on Data in Snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/alerts) and sending email notification using [SYSTEM$SEND_EMAIL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures/system_send_email):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE ALERT alert_new_table_named_tbl
WAREHOUSE = my_warehouse   -- alert warehouse
SCHEDULE = '15 MINUTE'     -- alert schedule
IF (EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM <DATABASE_NAME>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE TABLE_NAME ILIKE '%tbl%'
))
THEN CALL SYSTEM$SEND_EMAIL(...);
```

Comment: This is helpful, Thanks. can I incorporate this code in python .will it work ? if so how.it would be helpful if you help me with the sample python code .since i have to give solution as a python code.